# ui.Chart.image.series() function does not work when app published

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart

I have created an app using Google Earth Engine which makes a Regional Time Series Chart of a specified geometry.

This is the code:

```
function generateData() {
  regionalTimeSeries.clear();
  var chart = ui.Chart();
  var col = ee.ImageCollection(table[select.getValue()][dataType]).select(table[select.getValue()].band).filterDate(ee.Date(ds1.getValue()[0]), ee.Date(ds2.getValue()[0]));
  var correctedCol = col;
  if (table[select.getValue()].unit == "µmol/m^2") {
    correctedCol = col.map(multiply);
  }
  chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
    imageCollection: correctedCol,
    region: draw.layers().get(0).geometries().get(0),
    reducer: ee.Reducer.median()
  });
  chart.setOptions({
    interpolateNulls: true,
    width: "100%",
    height: "90%",
    title: select.getValue() + " - Variation in Time",
    vAxis: {
      title: table[select.getValue()].short + " (" +table[select.getValue()].unit + ")",
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: "Time"
    },
    curveType: 'function',
    series: {
     0: {visibleInLegend: false}
    },
    explorer: {axis: 'vertical'}
  });
  chart.setChartType('LineChart');
  chart.style().set('width', "100%");
  print(chart.getDataTable());
  regionalTimeSeries.add(chart);
}

function multiply(img) {
  return img.multiply(1e6).copyProperties(img, ['system:time_start']);
}
```

Everything works fine in the Code Editor, but when I published the app it shows the error in the Developer Tools Console:

> Uncaught Error: Malformed Google Visualization API DataTable source.
> Please provide a 2-D array, a DataTable literal, or a JSON string of a
> DataTable literal.

The chart is not loading and when I try to print the DataTable in GEE (using `chart.getDataTable()`, it return `[]`. Also, if I try to print the data table in code editor, it return `[]` but the chart is still loading without a data table.

[This](https://showcase.earthengine.app/view/tropomi-explorer#dataset=Nitrogen%20dioxide;datatype=Near-real-time;center=%7B%22type%22%3A%22Point%22%2C%22coordinates%22%3A%5B-110.70338309345125%2C39.176359203033236%5D%7D;aoi=%7B%22type%22%3A%22Polygon%22%2C%22coordinates%22%3A%5B%5B%5B-112.54603881835938%2C40.41115227163401%5D%2C%5B-112.54603881835938%2C38.30476502089354%5D%2C%5B-109.11830444335938%2C38.30476502089354%5D%2C%5B-109.11830444335938%2C40.41115227163401%5D%5D%5D%2C%22geodesic%22%3Afalse%2C%22evenOdd%22%3Atrue%7D;cloud=10;leftdate=2020-01-01;rightdate=2020-02-01;min=20;max=400;swipe=false;chart=cont;zoom=6;) is an example of app which does the same but has no errors. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved the issue!

The problem was in this line `var chart = ui.Chart();`. This made Earth Engine to initialize the chart with no data, hence producing that error.

What I did was just to initialize the chart with data.

```
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: correctedCol,
  region: draw.layers().get(0).geometries().get(0),
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median()
});
```